# When generating new project using vaadin starter (v23), what are example users passwords?

Tags: vaadin

When generating new project using vaadin starter (v23), what are example users passwords? There are only hashes in data.sql and nothing in generated readme...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently it's user/user and admin/admin...